# Logrotate is not showing logs from 12AM to 6AM UTC

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, devops, rsyslog, logrotate

We are using logrotate tool for our AWS ec2 instances. Following is the script I am using in rsyslog file:

```bash
/opt/solr-6.5.0/server/logs/solr.log
{
        daily
        rotate 1
        missingok
        notifempty
        sharedscripts
        maxsize 500M
        copytruncate
        dateformat -%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S
        compress
        prerotate
                /usr/bin/find /opt/solr-6.5.0/server/logs/solr.log -mtime +0 -not -name '*.gz' 2>/dev/null -exec gzip {} \; || true
                /usr/bin/find /opt/solr-6.5.0/server/logs/solr.log -mtime +15 -delete 2>/dev/null || true
        endscript
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}
```

Note: The above script is being used for rotating solr logs.

**The issue is that logs from 12AM(00:00:00)UTC to 6:25:00UTC are not present in the log file.**
This is how the starting of the log file looks like:
[image: Log screenshot]
I want the logs should to be starting from 12AM UTC instead of 6:25AM UTC.

Please help me. I am stuck on this issue for last 3 months. Thanks in advance.

I have tried adding the sharedscripts and increased the maxsize from 50M to 500M, also tried adding the dateformat. But these changes did not fix the issue.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking - are you saying that the log is rotating at 6:25am and you don't know why? Maybe you need to find out when the log rotate is being run by cron. This question may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/198203/how-does-logrotate-exactly-handle-daily

Comment: Yes, I want the log to start at 12AM UTC instead of 6:25AM. 12AM to 6:25AM logs are not showing up in the log file. I checked the logrotate file inside cron.daily folder. This is what it shows:
#!/bin/sh

# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf

Comment: It looks like you need to check the schedule used for cron.daily: https://serverfault.com/a/1055674